# How to catch an assert with Google test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, assertions

I'm programming some unit test with the Google test framework. But I want to check whether some asserts are well placed and are useful. Is there a way to catch an assert in Google test?

Example code under test:

```
int factorial(int n){
    assert(n >= 0);
    //....
}
```

And then the test:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
TEST(FactorialTest,assertNegative){
    EXPECT_ANY_THROW({
         factorial(-1);
    });
}
```

But `EXPECT_ANY_THROW` doesn't catch the assert but only exceptions. I'm searching for a solution to catch asserts.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Google test provides [`ASSERT_DEATH`, `EXPECT_DEATH` and other related macros](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#death-tests).

This question and [What are Google Test, Death Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698718/what-are-google-test-death-tests) are each other's answers. Does that make them duplicates, or not? ;-)

Comment: Duplicate answers do not necessary constitute duplicate questions. However, your answer is essentially just a link---which is discouraged.

Comment: I have mentioned the names of the most relevant macros, so that if the link breaks then a reader has a basis to find up to date documentation.

Comment: Moved here: https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#death-tests

Answer (score 2):

EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE(statement,text) and EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE(statement,text) will **only pass** if 'statement' invokes a **failing** ASSERT_x or EXECT_x respectively.

These statements will pass in your tests:

`EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE( EXPECT_TRUE( 0 ), "" );
    EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE( ASSERT_TRUE( 0 ), "" );`

Comment: These statements are not available. I get `error: ‘EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘EXPECT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE’?` and `error: macro "EXPECT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1`. How do you get them?