# How to bypass assert in unit test in Debug mode?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, assert, catch-unit-test

In a test case I would like to test a function which in debug mode generates an assertion for invalid input. This unfortunately stops [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) test runner. Is there any way to bypass this assertion so that the test runner keeps going ?

Here is my test case:

```
 SCENARIO("Simple test case", "[tag]") {
    GIVEN("some object") {
        MyObject myobject;

        WHEN("object is initialized with invalid data") {
            // method init generates an assertion when parameters are invalid
            bool result = myObject.init(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
            REQUIRE(false == result);

            THEN("data processing can't be started") {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assertions are there to guard against cases that should *never* happen in a correct program. Why are you unit-testing that ? If invalid parameters may happen within a correct program (from malformed user input, for example), you should use exceptions instead of assertions.

Comment: @Quentin In fact it is an external library (generated by Matlab code generator) which I want to test. We generated a wrapper to the generated code but don't really now if the library can handle invalid data which might happen in the real life as they come from input files. I agree that using of exceptions might be a better solution than an asserts in our case.

Comment: This seems very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/38533272/102345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `assert` is a macro doing something like

```
#define assert(e) ((void) ((e) \
  ? 0 
  : (void)printf ("%s:%u: failed assertion `%s'\n",  __FILE__, __LINE__, #e),
    abort(), // <-- this aborts you program after printf's above
    0        
)
```

and this macro is enabled in debug builds. For more specifics, look into your standard `assert.h`

So, if you have a binary library against which you link your test cases, you will need to tell the dev team that, unless they gave you a release build with no asserts enabled, you won't be able to unit-test their API for negative test cases.

If you need to test a header-only library or you compile against the source code to be tested, you'll need to

1. compile your test cases/suite with -DNDEBUG; *and/or*
2. define your own `assert` macro (e,g. to throw an error which you'll catch) and hope that your specific `assert.h` will test if already defined and won't try to define it again (again, look for specifics in your compiler/std libs `assert.h` header)