# How to suppress runtime errors caused by assert() using google test?

Tags: c++, assert, runtime-error, googletest

I am using google test in a C++ project. Some functions use assert() in order to check for invalid input parameters. I already read about Death-Tests ([What are Google Test, Death Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698718/what-are-google-test-death-tests)) and started using them in my test cases.

However, I wonder if there is a way to suppress the runtime errors caused by failing assertions. At this time each failing assertion creates a pop-up window I have to close everytime I run the tests. As my project grows, this behaviour increasingly disturbs the workflow in an unacceptable way and I tend to not test assert()-assertions any longer. 
I know there are possibilities to disable assertions in general, but it seems more convenient to suppress the OS-generated warnings from inside the testing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself: You have to select the test-style `threadsafe`. Just add the following line to your test code:

```
::testing::FLAGS_gtest_death_test_style = "threadsafe";
```

You can either do this for all tests in the test-binary or for affected tests only. The latter is faster. I got this from the updated FAQ: [Googletest AdvancedGuide](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#death-test-styles)